# How to split a string up and save it to a variable if it is valid?

Tags: java, string, split

I'm having some problems splitting a string that is read in from an input file, making sure it's valid, then saving it to a variable.

Let's say this is the first string:
12345 5 59.28

I would want to split the 12345, 5, and 59.28. 
After verifying that they are the correct format ( 00000-99999, 0-5, 000.00 0 100.00 ), I would then assign it to a variable.

My main two obstacles are that I CANNOT use arrays in this program, so I'm not sure how to split the string. I have tried just pulling each section as an int, but that doesn't seem to work.

My other problem is that I'm not sure how to validate it. Would I be using something like this:

```
//Assuming I have a scanner set up and a class, method declared

//Declare variables
int numbers;
int studentID;

while(fileInput.hasNext())
  {
    numbers = fileInput.nextInt(); //Not sure how to pull a part of the string
  }

//Used to validate that it is within the range
if(numbers < 00000 || numbers > 99999)
  {
    studentID = numbers;
  }
```

I am a beginner at Java so please do excuse my confusion.

Comment: Why can't you use arrays?  It seems that you're best to use the `split` method of the `String` class, which returns an array.

Comment: Javascript question tag and code snippets removed -- this question has **nothing** to do with programming in Javascript.

Comment: What, exactly, do you want to assign to a variable?  You're dealing with four numbers in the string.  If you want to assign each one of those into a variable, then don't you pretty much need an array?  Please don't tell me you're going to declare a bunch of variables like `variable1`, `variable2`, `variable3`, etc.  Or do you want to assign the entire string to a variable after checking for validity?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem We aren't allowed to use anything that apparently wasn't teached before we were assigned it.

Comment: @ajb There are 3 numbers in the string. And yes. We are supposed to declare "as much variables as needed" and assign them after validating that they fit the format that I mentioned above.

Comment: I guess you could call `next` in a `Scanner` over and over, and process the strings that come out.  It seems a bit of a crazy limitation though.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Yes. I know and that's why I'm having so much problems when using arrays would be much easier. Sadly, I would probably get a failed grade if I do use arrays, since the assignment says to specifically not use an array. Yea but I'm having a problem understanding how to split the string that has three numbers that I need to assign to different variables.

Comment: I despair of teachers like yours.  Do they think they're being clever, teaching you a less-than-optimal way of doing something?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Haha I'm not sure. This is only my intro class to CS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Invalid formats will throw an exception during the `next` method call.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner("12345 5 59.28");
    in.useDelimiter(" "); // reads per space

    String next = in.next("\\d{5}");  // reads next 5 digits
    int numbers = Integer.valueOf(next);
    System.out.println(numbers);

    next = in.next("\\d{1}"); // reads next 1 digit
    int studentId = Integer.valueOf(next);
    System.out.println(studentId);

    next = in.next("\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}"); // reads next a decimal with two digits before and after point
    float floatingNumbers = Float.valueOf(next);
    System.out.println(floatingNumbers);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="//repl.it/embed/IWzC/0.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hmmm... he's not allowed to use arrays, I wonder if he's allowed to use regexes?

Comment: What OP said was _"We aren't allowed to use anything that apparently wasn't teached before we were assigned it."_

Comment: Well forgive me for not seeing that, but that piece of information was left out. The code I've written meets 100% of the OP's original requirements; I do not, and cannot, satisfy requirements I am not aware of.

Comment: @EyuelDK shouldn't the comment "reads next 4 digits" be replaced with "reads next 5 digits"?

Answer (score 0):

If you know what the structure of the file is, for example if it's always formatted like this:

```
int int double
```

Then you can simply call`nextInt()`, `nextInt()`, and then `nextDouble()` to parse the data from it that way.

Maybe something like this

```
do
{
    num1 = scanner.nextInt();
    num2 = scanner.nextInt();
    num3 = scanner.nextDouble();
} while (scanner.hasNextInt());
```

And do that in order to collect all of your data, but you'll likely need lots of variables if you have any substantial amount of data you're reading in

Or if there's bad data sometimes with it's correct data immediately after it you could so something like this to skip over the bad one, even though it's not very pretty

```
do
{
    if (scanner.hasNextInt())
    {
        num1 = scanner.nextInt();
    }
    else
    {
        scanner.next() // move past whatever bad data there was
        num1 = scanner.nextInt();
    }

    if (scanner.hasNextInt())
    {
        num2 = scanner.nextInt();
    }
    else
    {
        scanner.next() // move past whatever bad data there was
        num2 = scanner.nextInt();
    }

    if (scanner.hasNextDouble())
    {
        num3 = scanner.nextDouble();
    }
    else
    {
        scanner.next() // move past whatever bad data there was
        num3 = scanner.nextDouble();
    }
} while (scanner.hasNext());
```

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem You're correct. The program would exit with a stack trace but that's why I prefixed this answer with "If you know what the structure of the file is". This student isn't looking for a bullet-proof-unbreakable solution. Just one that will help with his/her studies.

Comment: @MichaelFlaherty Actually, if it isn't valid I'm supposed to go on with the program and just ignore the data that isn't valid.

Comment: @Amai Do you know exception handling yet?

Comment: @MichaelFlaherty No. The only thing I've learned concerning to exception is to put the words "throw IOException" to the method every time you deal with a file.

Comment: @Amai Cool, that's okay. Look at what I added to my original answer. This should parse over bad data just fine. If you had "32 3m2 32 42.4" It'd skip the 3m2

Answer (score 0):

I think your teachers give this assignment to practice your if-else condition or switch statement and for loop(fundamental) skills.

Here what I did, this may be not completely match with your assignment question but using this you can get complete idea and think of a way to reduce this. Hey! because of we are not here to do your assignment. you have to tackle with your problem and get familiar with those.

Try to understand these, do changes look what happen:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Declare variables
    String numbers = "";

    String firstNum = "";
    String secondNum = "";
    String thirdNum = "";

    int studentID = 0;
    int secondDigit = 0;
    double thirdDigit = 0;

    System.out.print("Input: ");
    numbers = fileInput.nextLine(); 

    int firstIndex = 0;
    int secondIndex = 0;
    int thirdIndex = 0;

    firstIndex = numbers.indexOf(" ");
    if(firstIndex <= 4){
        System.out.println("Number should be 5");
    }else{

        firstNum = numbers.substring(0, firstIndex);
        numbers = numbers.substring(firstIndex+1);

        studentID = Integer.parseInt(firstNum);

        if(studentID > 0 && studentID < 99999){
            System.out.println("First num: " +firstNum);
        }else{
            System.out.println("first digits not in a range ");
        }
    }

    secondIndex = numbers.indexOf(" ");
    if(secondIndex == 0){
        System.out.println("no number");
    }else{
        secondNum = numbers.substring(0, secondIndex);

        numbers = numbers.substring(secondIndex+1);

        secondDigit = Integer.parseInt(secondNum);

        if(secondDigit >= 0 && secondDigit <= 5){
            System.out.println("Second num: " +secondNum);
        }else{
            System.out.println("second digit not in a range ");
        }
    }


    thirdIndex = numbers.length();
    if(thirdIndex < 3){
        System.out.println("3 numbers should be there");
    }else{
        thirdNum = numbers.substring(0, thirdIndex);
        thirdDigit = Double.parseDouble(thirdNum);

        if(thirdDigit >= 0 && thirdDigit <= 100){
            System.out.println("third num: " +thirdNum);
        }else{
            System.out.println("third digit not in a range ");
        }
    }  
}
```

I'm not going to explain this also. You have to try, if you have any problem after tackling with this code. ask any question in comment.

Hope this will help!

Comment: @Amai: try this. ask any question from comment after tackle with this. I did not explain it because you have to practice. Practice make you perfect!

Comment: This was helpful ^ - ^
Thanks a bunches